# Send a .csv from Blob storage to a Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure

i'm new on Azure and i have to do 2 things:

1. I have a file_1.csv and a schema_1.json for the db schema. I want to send the file_1.csv into a DB on Azure with respect to the schema in the shema_1.json.
2. I have to create a pipeline with 2 branches: the first takes file_A.csv, converts it to .json, save the .json in Blob Storage and in a SQL DB. the second branch takes the saved .json, does a join with a file_B.csv and writes the result in the SQL DB (as an updated version of the file_A data).

I'm not asking for the complete code to do this, just some indications on what services i should use as i'm completely lost.

I did it on GCP (i used a bucket, bigquery to store the .json schema and the sql db and Dataflow to do the pipeline) and AWS

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ . I think it might suit your use case.

Comment: Or if you want to code it out you can use [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview). Since you deal with file uploads (.csv and after that a .json file) you can use blob triggered azure functions for example.

Comment: i did a function that triggers on blob, it works. however, i don't know which service to use as a DB (i have the schema and the data, but idk how to insert it in a DB)

Comment: Well it depends on why you want it in a database and what you want to do with it once the data is in. Because you can choose between lots of options, like relational databases or no-sql databases for example.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say it should be in a relational db

Comment: Agreed with @PeterBons for your requirement I think Azure data factory will suit you to convert and transfer the files and then aging combine it and store it in sql database. also it has triggers when file is uploaded in storage account.

Comment: thanks for your answers, PeterBons and PratikLad

Comment: You're welcome. For databases see [Azure Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/?view=azuresql)

Comment: form here you will get more information on [relational databases](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/products/category/databases/) on azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the discussion in the comments.

> 1. I have to create a pipeline with 2 branches: the first takes file_A.csv, converts it to .json, save the .json in Blob Storage and in a SQL DB. the second branch takes the saved .json, does a join with a file_B.csv and writes the result in the SQL DB (as an updated version of the file_A data).

You can use combination of ADF [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) and [Data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) here.

First use the copy activity to convert csv file to JSON in Blob storage. In copy activity source, give the source csv dataset and in sink, give target JSON dataset with file name.

[image]

Then in dataflow activity create a mapping dataflow. In that take two sources one for the 2nd csv file in the Blob storage and another one for the JSON that we are getting after copy activity. So, Give the datasets according to it.

To join them, use a join transformation in the data flow for the both sources and give the key for the join as per your requirement.

In the sink of the dataflow, give the SQL database dataset like below and Execute the above pipeline.

[image]